# Hide JQueryUI Tooltips When Printing

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using JQueryUI tooltips on several components in my application, and they work well. However, they linger over components when tapped in the Chrome mobile browser - a feature which I actually rather like - but if I print while they're displayed, the tooltip prints, too.

I tried adding

```
@media print
{
   .ui-tooltip
    {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

to my stylesheet, without success, although I can use that selector to style other aspects of the tooltip, like colors and fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery UI Tooltip adds `display: block;` to the element when inserted into the dom, the inline styling can only be overwritten with `!important`, which is bad practice and can be avoided with `visibility: hidden;`

```
@media print
{
   .ui-tooltip
    {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

Normally, this would be an issue because `visibility: hidden;` allows the hidden element to take up space. But because the nature of tooltips is to be positioned absolutely, that wont be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just hiding **.ui-tooltip** was not enough. I had to hide **.ui-helper-hidden-accessible** as well.